# Are there technical differences between "cond && {...}" and "if (cond) { ...}"?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

Sometimes when I'm reading through other people's code (specifically PHP, but this question refers to all programming languages), I see something like the following:

```
some_bool_value && return = some_function()
```

After some thought, I realized that they were using this in place of:

```
if(some_bool_value){ return = some_function() }
```

Is there any programmatic benefit to this alternative method, or is it just a shorthand/preference?

Comment: I don't know the benefit of it, but to me, it is not a bonus to readability.

Comment: I rarely see this pattern with `&&`, but with `||` it's pretty common. Typically to supply default values or to show an error if the value isn't specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is programmers shorthand.  In this case, it is known as short-circuit evaluation (If the left side of the `&&` evaluates to true/non-zero, the right side is evaluated.  Otherwise, the right side is not evaluated).

This type of thing falls under personal preference and style of the programmer or team and is not related to efficiency in any practical sense.